# Is there a way to change the bios message that shows upon booting the computer?

Tags: boot, bios

Recently purchased a PowerSpec PC from Microcenter (their inhouse brand) and upon booting it displays the PowerSpec logo.  Is there anyway this can be changed?

Comment: Not without re-flashing with a custom ROM image/bin file.

Comment: there might be an option in BIOS to disable the splash screen.

Comment: I once had an abit board that let me add images for custom splash. it was much more trouble than it was worth. most firmware does let you turn off the splash, but that will vary from vendor to vendor. Also Powerspec doesn't build their own motherboards, so you can probably find out who actually built it, and you may find more options from them. personally if I'm going to buy a prebuilt system, I like powerspec, because it won't generally have any proprietary parts, so you are free to repair and upgrade as you see fit

Answer (score 1):

The firmware (UEFI, not BIOS, which isn't used since more than decade ago) may or may not have a setting for that.

What you're seeing now is a "splash" screen and you may be able to change it to a more verbose boot and not show the logo. Again,this entirely depends on the vendor enabling such feature/setting.

Other than standard settings you'd need to either flash a custom ROM or "extract" and modify the one currently in use. Needless to say if you're asking this question then likely you don't have the skills required and you shouldn't attempt to do it because you risk bricking the computer.

Comment: so I've never like nitpicking about the BIOS vs UEFI terminology, and I think I just figured out why I don't like referring to "UEFI"; its not really a noun in the same way BIOS is, so I end up having to use awkward phrasing or ambiguous terms (eg "firmware"). The "I" is the problem. motherboard firmware is not an "interface". that software is written to conform to an extensible interface, and it displays an (user) interface, and the OS software uses "interfaces" like ACPI to interact with it, but mobofirmware is code on a ROM. I should be able to say "my/his/her/their uefi", but its wrong.

Comment: @FrankThomas I don't like it either but that was the consortium's decision. Insisting on using "BIOS" is the same as calling a (motor) car an horse carriage and "UEFI BIOS" that so many vendors are using nowadays a "motorized horseless horse carriage" (well, that actually happened some 120-130 years ago).

Comment: that's an interesting take; I got a chuckle out of that. that said though, what UEFI actually is, is a means for a motherboard to accept ROM code that performs BIOS functions that unifies several parties takes on how to provide extensible capabilities, so its a standard, implemented in hardware. When I say "My BIOS" I'm referring to the bits electromagnetically stored on MY ROM, not anyone else's, and I'm referring to the code, not the pins and circuitry that lets the mobo read that ROM and do stuff with it. and I know, this isn't your doing; don't feel like you need to defend it ;-)